# Xcode commands are taking a long time within Flutter projects

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild, flutter-ios

### Some context

I'm working with Flutter, but after doing a couple of changes to the iOS `Podfile`, `.plist` files, and `Runner.xcworkspace` things "stopped" working. The problem I'm having is that everything Xcode related is taking a very long time to run in all of my Flutter projects.

To give some context the app I was building when Xcode started giving me problems uses Cloud Firestore. For this to compile faster I added the following code to my `Podfile`, this was suggested by [Google in some docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#dart:%7E:text=Optional%3A%20Improve%20iOS%20%26%20macOS%20build%20times%20by%20including%20the%20pre%2Dcompiled%20framework.).

```
platform :ios, '16.1'

target 'Runner' do
  # Code to reduce compile time for iOS.
  pod 'FirebaseFirestore/WithLeveldb', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '10.2.0'
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end
```

After doing this change and importing the Firestore package a file called `GoogleService-Info.plist` was created and I added this file to the `Runner.xcworkspace` as a Runner. This step was [mentioned in another Google document](https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-auth-in-flutter-apps#6:%7E:text=Right%2Dclick%20on%20the%20Runner%20directory%20and%20select%20Add%20Files%20to%20%22Runner%22.) for activating sign-in with Google.

A weird thing about all of this is that if I try to run `open Runner.xcworkspace` the Xcode app also takes forever to open (it's been over an hour since I ran it and it has not been opened). This worked earlier as I was able to open this directory to make the aforementioned change (make `GoogleService-Info.plist` a Runner file).

### Attempts to solve this

After identifying the error I tried doing the following things, but nothing has worked so far:

- Uninstall Xcode Command Line Tools and install them back on.
- Uninstall Flutter and install it back on.
- Uninstall Xcode completely and install it back on.
- Restart my computer.
- Try to build the project in another computer, but now this other computer is having the same issue.

I've tried to run things on both an Intel-based Mac and an Apple Silicon Mac, but in both computers Xcode "stopped" working for Flutter.

### Reproducing this problem

The problem occurs when I try to run `flutter clean`, `flutter run`, or `open Runner.xcworkspace`. After running the first two commands in `--verbose` mode the problem comes up when the following commands appear:

1. `xcrun xcodebuild -list`
2. `xcrun xcodebuild -workspace $PATH/Runner.xcworkspace -scheme Flutter Assamble clean`
3. `xcrun xcodebuild -workspace $PATH/Runner.xcworkspace -scheme Runner clean`

The first command is currently running on the Apple Silicon Mac and its already been over an hour since it's been stuck there (Intel-based Mac already finished running this command). The second command follows the first one and it took over 20 minutes for it to run in the Intel computer. The third command is currently running on the Intel-based computer and it's been there for over 40 minutes.

### Final details

This problem is persistent in all of my Flutter projects, it doesn't matter if the project has the Firebase packages or not. I don't know what I could have changed in my Xcode configuration for things to stop working so abruptly, but I hope someone is able to help me out.

> P.S. I already tried compiling a native Swift project and everything seems to work, this issue seems to affect the Flutter projects exclusively. Obviously if I try to run the commands listed earlier outside of the Flutter execution they take a very long time as well.

Answer (score 0):

After running more tests I realized that the problem was iCloud. For some reason working on both computers at the same time made my local computers work very slowly. The problem was hard to find because the [iCloud **bird** process](https://iboysoft.com/news/mac-process-bird-high-cpu.html) didn't appear to use more resources than it usually would.

To solve this I had to kill iCloud on both computers and restart the service. I recently updated both computers to Ventura 13.0.1 so I think the problem might be somewhere along those lines.